Where did Russell eulogize mathematics as follows?
A colleague told me that Bertrand Russell expressed:

“Mathematics, rightly viewed, possesses not only truth, but supreme beauty — a beauty cold and austere, like that of sculpture, without appeal to any part of our weaker nature, without the gorgeous trappings of painting or music, yet sublimely pure, and capable of a stern perfection such as only the greatest art can show.”

The colleague surmises that it is from A History of Western Philosophy.
May someone help with finding the precise bibliographical informations, please?

Accordung to WIkiQuote https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Bertrand_Russell#%22The_Study_of_Mathematics%22_(November_1907) your colleague is not correct.

He surmised ...

@njuffa Thanks, I just posted that as an answer. :)

@njuffa But there seems to be a discrepancy as regards publisher ...

@mdewey has a third publisher, it seems ...

Maybe the book was published in UK and USA at the same time.

@njuffa I know, I am cleaning up towards including a proper bib-tex entry in the answer, as of now.
The publisher is George Allen & Unwin, and the publication year is 1917.

Bertrand Russell, "The Study of Mathematics." The New Quarterly; a Review of Science and Literature, Vol. 1, No. 1, Nov. 1907, pp. 31-44. The text quoted in the question appears on p. 33.
This essay was later incorporated into collections of Russell's essays (thanks to Frode Alfson Bjørdal for the pointer to the first one):
Bertrand Russell, "The Study of Mathematics." In Philosophical Essays, London: Longmans, Green and Co. 1910, pp. 71-86. Quoted text appears on p. 73.
Bertrand Russell, "The Study of Mathematics." In Mysticism and Logic, and other Essays, London: George Allen & Unwin Ltd. 1917, pp. 58-73. Quoted text on p. 60.
Bertrand Russell, "The Study of Mathematics." In Mysticism and Logic, and other Essays, London: Longmans, Green and Co. 1918, pp. 58-73. There the quote appears on p. 60.

According to this https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Mysticism_and_Logic_and_Other_Essays, the book was "first published as as "Philosophical Essays" October 1910, Second Edition as "Mysticism and Logic December 1917".

May you post screenshots of the appearance in The New Quarterly, please?

Here, https://www.google.com/books/edition/New_Quarterly/BPgcAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0, the preview is unavailable, and I do not find samples of the referent which I can read.

I tried through University of Oslo, but nothing showed up through its library resources.

It is not readable through Google in Norway or  Brazil.

Anyway, it had been very nice to see the Vol. 1, No. 1, Nov. 1907, pp. 31-44 article. If it could be sent to me privately, I would very much appreciate it.

njuffa I asked a US colleague, and he is working on it. Hopefully  he succeeds.

My USA friend, from the student days, and colleague, helped me, and your 1907 reference worked! :) It seems to me, on account of the arguments in my answer, that the 1917 reference I gave is correct. As stated above, According to this en.wikisource.org/wiki/Mysticism_and_Logic_and_Other_Essays, the book was "first published as as "Philosophical Essays" October 1910, Second Edition as "Mysticism and Logic December 1917". But I have not found those Philosophical Essays, and it would have been interesting so include that as a reference, if it is correctly assigned.

As per the previous comment, en.wikisource.org/wiki/Mysticism_and_Logic_and_Other_Essays stated that Mysticism_and_Logic_and_Other_Essays was first published as "Philosophical Essays" in October 1910. That is not true, for I checked those "Philosophical Essays" by means of the Internet Archive, and it does not have the particular chapter Mysticism and Logic.

njuffa As the 1907 reference is rather out of bonds for book consumers, as witnessed as well by my difficulties, the important problem which remains for me is whether it was London: Longmans, Green and Co. 1918, or London: George Allen & Unwin 1917. For it is not appropriate, I think, to refer to books which the audience may bot obtain. \ldots

njuffa Right. Anyway, how may I decide btw. London: Longmans, Green and Co. 1918, or London: George Allen & Unwin 1917, I wonder. At this point I lean towards relying upon the evidence provided by the two e-book samples, which I linked to.

njuffa What technology do you use?

I inspected the online 1918 version from the Oslo University library, but did not see the bibliographical information in the beginning pages. Now I am downloading the whole book as pdf, to see if that helps.

njuffa This settles it, as I think, and you are right.
Cano you see it?
https://archive.org/details/mysticismlogicot00russuoft/page/n7/mode/2up.

We should agree, I think, that both the 1917 and 1918 references are correct. What I will do is to make a separate bibliography entry to the article "The Study of Mathematics", and in that entry inform that it appeared in the 1907, 1910, 1917 and 1918 entries. Thank you very much for your help! :)

The quote is from

Bertrand Russell: Mysticism and Logic, Chapter IV, p. 60.

According to Philpapers a correct bibtex-entry is:
@book{Russell1918-RUSMAL,
address = {Mineola, N.Y.},
author = {Bertrand Russell},
editor = {},
publisher = {Dover Publications},
title = {Mysticism and Logic},
year = {1918}
}
However, it seems, from the exchanges here, and searches, that the following bibtex-entry, for the UK-publication, is correct. For justification on this, see the on-line version here: Mysticism and Logic
@book{Russell1917, author = {Bertrand Russell}, title = {Mysticism and Logic}, date = {1917}, publisher = {George Allen & Unwin}, location = {location}, chapter = {IV}, pages = {60}, url =www.en.wikisource.org/wiki/Mysticism_and_Logic_and_Other_Essays, urldate = {20.08.2024}}
Update: Here is more evidence for the \cite{Russell1917} reference: Mysticism and Logic e-book from Gutenberg
Update 2: So I will accept njuffa's 1907 answer, but I first want to settle the doubts concerning the 1910 answer I mentioned.

@Somo See my comments above to njuffa. The first publication was in UK. I made a bib-tex entry which Texstudioate, so I will write it again right now.

@Somos Here is the bibtex entry, which I just recuperated. Notice the publisher. @book{Russell1918, author = {Bertrand Russell}, title = {Mysticism and Logic}, date = {1917}, publisher = {George Allen & Unwin}, location = {location}, chapter = {IV}, pages = {60}, url =www.en.wikisource.org/wiki/Mysticism_and_Logic_and_Other_Essays, urldate = {20.08.2024} }
